# Could not find dagger-2.13-2.13.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13)

Tags: android, gradle, dagger

I'm trying to develop my first Android app using Dagger, but I'm having some trouble compiling it.

When I compile the project, the console shows the error below:

```
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException:
Could not find dagger-2.13-2.13.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13).
```

I think that the problem is in Gradle configuration because the project try's to sync a package with the version duplicated `dagger-2.13-2.13.jar` but in my grade file the version is only 2.13.

My gradle file is:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'kotlin-android'
  id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
  id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 30

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "co.megusta.countries"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
  }
}

def lifeCycleExtensionsVersion = "1.1.1"
def supportVersion = "28.0.0"
def retrofitVersion = "2.3.0"
def daggerVersion = "2.13"
def glideVersion = "4.8.0"
def mockitoVersion = "2.11.0"
def rxJavaVersion = "2.0.1"

dependencies {
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
  implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

  implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
  implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
  implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofitVersion"

  implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
  implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"

  implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
  implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"

  kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
  kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

  implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportVersion"

  implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"

  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"

  implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycleExtensionsVersion"

  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
  testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockitoVersion"

  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_agp_internal_javaPreCompileDebug_kaptClasspath'.
   > Could not find dagger-2.13-2.13.jar (com.google.dagger:dagger:2.13).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/dagger/dagger/2.13/dagger-2.13-2.13.jar
```

Anyone know what I'm  doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Replace `jcenter()` with `mavenCentral()`.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I replaced the repository, but the problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem I need to update the minSdk to 21. After that everything works as expected.

See my final build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "co.megusta.c3"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

def lifeCycleExtensionsVersion = '2.5.0'
def recyclerViewVersion = '1.2.1'
def recyclerViewSelectVersion = '1.1.0'
def retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'
def daggerVersion = '2.42'
def glideVersion = '4.13.2'
def mockitoVersion = '4.6.1'
def rxJavaVersion = '3.0.0'

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava3:$retrofitVersion"

    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"

    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glideVersion"

    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerViewVersion"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:$recyclerViewSelectVersion"
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:$recyclerViewSelectVersion"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifeCycleExtensionsVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifeCycleExtensionsVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifeCycleExtensionsVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifeCycleExtensionsVersion"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifeCycleExtensionsVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-inline:$mockitoVersion"
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```